# presentModalViewController and navigationController

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I want to know the differences between the

`[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];`

and

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

I have used both but still do not know or noticed the difference. when should use one of them ?

Thanks..

Comment: Summary of the Apple Developer Documentation: Most commonly, applications use modal view controllers as a temporary interruption in order to obtain key information from the user. Navigation Controllers are used to manage the presentation of hierarchical data. Or is your question "What happens behind the scenes?"

Comment: so can I say if I want to display different view from current and get back to the current view then I should use presentModalViewController ?

Comment: If different means a Question like "what do you want to do with this picture? -> upload -> delete -> cancel" and after that action you return to your picture, then yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presenting a modal view is presenting a view on top of another view. You perform those typically for "tasks" that need to be started and completed in a self contained way. Read further on modal views on the apple developer guides.

Pushing a view on to the navigation controller is different where there is a logical need for navigation in the app. Say a drill down table as in the setting app of the iDevices, where there are main settings then you drill down to sub settings etc.

Whatever your questions are, if they are conceptual and generic as this I'd strongly advise you to google up "X  programming guide" which will take you to the proper Apple programming guide :) X = view controller in your case

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

**Basic difference :**

`pushViewController` only works in **navigation controllers**

`presentModalViewController` works for **all view controllers**

**navigationController** is the instance of your `UINavigationController`, which is used by all the controller in your navigation stack (`UIViewController`).

Answer (score 2):

if base class has it's own NavigationController then you can write:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:objMyViewController animated:YES];
```

if your base class has only UIViewController then use:

```
MyViewController * objMyViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController * navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objMyViewController];
navController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem  = nil;  // make nil if you want
                                                        // to use it in next View
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

now, MyViewController has navigation so you can -- Push -- another viewController by writing function as bellow in MyViewController.

```
-(IBAction)btnNext_click {
    SecondViewController * objSecondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objSecondViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: but the second view will appear behind the modal view controller